# find out what triggers bash file (.sh) on the server

Tags: linux, bash, sh, daemon, zombie-process

I have php script on "first" Linux server that publishes websites on "second" Linux server. websites are being published just fine, except permissions and ownership for files and folder getting changed and make websites crash. So, I found the bash script on "second" Linux Server that changes it. But I don't understand what triggers it. There is nothing in php code that would trigger. And I don't know how to find these daemon or zombie process that get trigger when certain event happens. can someone help how to find that?

Comment: For a definitive answer, I'd suggest using sysdig (http://sysdig.org/) to track its execution -- you can trivially ask for the parent process every time it's executed, or a dump of the process tree whenever execution occurs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A cronjob could have been set to trigger this bash script to run. You can view crons for the current user with the command `crontab -l`
If it is a cron, edit the crontab with `crontab -e` and delete/edit the line that is causing the bash script to run. Alternatively you can just usr `crontab -r` to remove all the crons for the user